# How do delete a PIL Image?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am trying to replace an Image file using Python PIL.

```
im = Image.open(logo_dir+cat_string_im)
```

What function do I call to delete the original file?

im.delete() or im.replace() don't work.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`os.remove()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove) to delete the file. This is basic functionality, so it's not too likely that every module that works with files also includes facilities for file copying, moving, deletion, etc.

```
os.remove(logo_dir+cat_string_im)
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need PIL to delete the image. You can do it with

```
os.remove(path, *, dir_fd=None)
```

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.remove